# show $\lim_{n\to \infty } (1+\frac{1}{n})^n =e$

Tags: real-analysis

This is an example in Applied Anlysis book that
$$ \lim_ {n\to \infty} \left (1+\frac{1}{n} \right )^n=e. $$
The author just says it is an example of convergent sequence.

I'm wondering what technique is needed to prove it using $\epsilon$-$N$ definition.

Comment: The technique you need will depend on how you define $e$. One definition is $e := \exp 1$ where $\exp r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left({1 + \frac r n}\right)^n$, in which case you just need to prove that the limit converges to *something*.

Comment: Write it as a binomial series, after apply your knowledge of convergence of series. I dont know any approach from complex analysis, sorry.

Comment: its been a while since I taken analysis and anytime I see $e$ I think of $e^{i\theta}$ that is all

Comment: @jack I can't delete it now that there is an aswer. I looked at similar questions and searched for it. I swear

Comment: Start by : Let $y=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, then take $ln$ on both sides. Your limit will converge to $1$, i.e $\ln{e}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)=n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=n\left(\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

so:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)=1$$ and thus because $\exp$ is continuous, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$

Comment: This is not a proof, you are using natural logarithm (already based in something that you want to prove that exist) and the previously knowledge that the natural logarithm of $e$ is 1. This is very circular.

Comment: you want to prove that $e$ exists ?

Comment: @Masacroso You can define $\ln$ without using $e$ by saying $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac 1 t \, \mathrm dt$ and then noting $\ln x = 1$ has a unique solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right @GFauxPas, my bad.

Comment: yes, GFauxPas is right, $e=\exp(1)$ where $\exp$ is defined as the inverse function of $\ln$ and you prove first equality by making a change of variable $t=v^n$ in the definition of $\ln$ given by GFauxPas